# When is Hawkeye (2021) set relative to Spider-Man: No Way Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home, hawkeye-2021

Simple question: does *Hawkeye* (2021) start after the end of *Spider-man: No Way Home*, or are the series’ near Christmas events when Rogers: The Musical is playing coincident in time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [this site's analysis](https://www.denofgeek.com/movies/spider-man-no-way-home-set-post-blip-mcu-timeline/), likely *Spider-Man: No Way Home* precedes *Hawkeye (2021)*

> **Spider-Man: No Way Home** picks up directly after the events of **Far From Home**, which means it also takes place in 2024, though heading into the start-of-school/fall season.
>
> **Hawkeye** is set at the end of 2024, during the Christmas season. It sees Clint Barton dealing with the consequences of his tenure as Ronin, the vigilante alter-ego he took on during the Blip.

It seems likely that *No Way Home* ends before the end of *Hawkeye*, as the Rockefeller Center appears to be fine in the final scene.

Comment: Can’t fault that analysis. Pretty convincing.

Comment: They have a bit of further information to firmly establish the 2024 year for both works, FWIW.

Comment: _No Way Home_ runs from the end of _Far From Home_ to that year’s Christmas, so I figure that’s the same time as Hawkeye.

Comment: Also, the renovations to the Statue of Liberty are mentioned in Hawkeye by Yelena Belova: "new and improved Statue of Liberty"

Comment: Which presumably means the shield was restored after the battle there. The Rockefeller tree looks fine in _No Way Home_, so perhaps at least the _Hawkeye_ finale is set after the events of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

#### The official timeline puts *Hawkeye* after *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

The official source for the MCU timeline is the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, which gives the chronological order of the events in the movies and shows. This book reveals that *Spider-Man: No Way Home* takes place in the fall of 2024, and wraps up in December 2024. The book states: “Just before Christmas, Spider-Man plunges through Rockefeller Center, where Hawkeye will soon fight Kingpin’s minions.”

This means that the events of *No Way Home*, including the final scenes, happen before the start of *Hawkeye*, which begins in December 2024. *Hawkeye* is the last story in the official timeline that occurs in 2024.

Here are the relevant sections from the book, presented in chronological order:

###### Start of *No Way Home*

[image]

###### Conclusion of *No Way Home*

[image]

> ###### December 2024 | Fade Out
>
> Peter Parker has evaporated from the minds of everyone who once knew him, but he still remembers them. Just before the holidays, he visits the coffee shop where MJ works, hoping to finally reconnect with her and Ned. Ultimately, he decides they may be safer and happier not knowing him at all. Starting life over with a clean slate can be an amazing gift. Still, it is bittersweet to have been erased so completely.

> Just before Christmas, Spider-Man plunges through Rockefeller Center, where Hawkeye will soon fight Kingpin's minions.

###### Start of *Hawkeye*

[image]