# Why is "years" plural used to describe the gap between Ronin sightings?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time, hawkeye-2021

In *Hawkeye* Episode 1: "Never Meet Your Heroes", newscaster Pat Kiernan (who seems to be in a lot of MCU titles) mentions that it's been "years" since the Ronin has been sighted (in reference to the possible resurfacing of the Ronin, which is actually Kate). However, to my understanding, *Hawkeye* takes place in December 2023 - the same time as *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (hence the correlation in the Statue of Liberty changes). The Ronin was active in early 2023, killing members of organized crime, as seen in *Avengers: Endgame*. So the gap is, at most, nine or ten months, right? How, then, does this "years" between sightings add up in the MCU?

Comment: Related: [When is Hawkeye (2021) set relative to Spider-Man: No Way Home?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258314/7957)

Comment: Note that there is a difference between being sighted and being active. Osama bin Laden was active for years without being sighted, whereas the Loch Ness monster is being sighted all the time without being in any way active (or even existing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The newscaster’s statement about it being "years" since the last "sighting of the Ronin" is likely correct. According to *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, the events of [*Hawkeye* take place in **December 2024**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/281409/7957).

[image: part of Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline stating when Hawkeye took place - Fall 2024]

Clint Barton adopted the vigilante "Ronin" persona in **Spring 2018**, after the Snap wiped out his family. He continued his violent crusade against criminals until **Fall 2023**, when he rejoined the Avengers for the Time Heist in *Endgame*. It’s unclear how much of Ronin’s actions are known to the public, or when his last sighting was. So, in December 2024, when *Hawkeye* is set, it’s likely that it's been years since a "sighting of the Ronin."

[image: part of Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline quoted below]

> ##### Spring 2018-Fall 2023 | Ronin's Vengeance
>
> Grief rips apart Clint Barton. What emerges from within is the vigilante Ronin. How could he lose his wife, his sons, and his daughter, while criminals and killers live on—in some ways operating with more impunity than before? Barton abandons the mantle of Hawkeye and travels the world executing wrongdoers he feels don't deserve to live. While he feels his cause is righteous, his violent methods corrode his spirit. Among those he kills is gangster William Lopez, an act witnessed by William's daughter, Maya, who begins a quest for revenge against Ronin.

> Goodbye, Hawkeye: Clint Barton takes on a new identity.